# sample for facebook IPO in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I am trying to create a graph like : http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/05/17/business/dealbook/how-the-facebook-offering-compares.html?_r=0

Is there any d3.js code to start with on this graph?

Comment: View the source of that page?

Comment: i believe they are using jQuery and lot of other js files

Comment: Yes, but all the code to generate the graph is in there (albeit in an obfuscated manner).

Comment: Yes.I'm little confused as to which script refers to the exact visualization as shown when clicked on the stepper.

Comment: It would appear to be the code after `File: chart.js`.